# Unable to filter SQL results by current $_SESSION

Tags: php, mysql

So my end goal is to show all users where the designation is the same as the current currently logged in user.
This works fine when showing all results, but as soon as I try to filter by designation, no results are returned.

I suspect it is because I need to somehow define the "designation", but that is what I am unsure about.

```
$designation = $_SESSION['alogin'];
$sql = "SELECT * from  users WHERE designation = :designation";
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query-> bindParam(':designation', $designation, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

From other posts it seems to be correct, but I am most likely looking right over something.

The code I am using is premade I am just adding this filtering onto it.

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: Yup. Print out the value of `$_SESSION['alogin']` to make sure it's what you expect.

Comment: Please add sample data and the value of `$_SESSION['alogin']`

Comment: `$_SESSION['alogin']` brings back the email address of the logged in user. For my case it should be showing what I want to filter by right?

Comment: @Barmar `$_SESSION['alogin']` returns the email of the logged in user. So I guess I need to store more data within the session right?


`array(1) {
  ["alogin"]=>
  string(25) "_email of logged in user removed for privacy_"
}`

Comment: Is that email stored in the `designation` column you're searching?

Comment: @ceejayoz nah the email is stored in the email column and designation holds the company name which is "Valentinos" in this case.

I can echo the designation just fine but as so as I run the SELECT query to filter it falls apart

Comment: Well, in that case, you're searching the wrong column; your query is doing something like `SELECT * from  users WHERE designation = 'foo@example.com'`. If you're trying to find the current user, and their email address is in that session value, you need to do `WHERE email = :whatever`.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong within my `$_SESSION` then because it is the correct column. When I get `$results->designation` I get the correct data.
Do I need to add the `designation` to my session somehow? I thought it would just pull all data related to who is logged in

Comment: OK, you're missing some serious SQL basics. `SELECT *` gets all the columns of data, including both `email` and `designation`. These columns of data are accessible in `$results`. The `WHERE` clause is how you're FILTERING the data. If you want to select the current user based on their email, you need to do something like `WHERE email=:email`, and set `:email` to the value of `$_SESSION['alogin']`.

Comment: I see what you are saying but with that it will just bring back that result of the logged in user.
My end goal is to being back all users with the same designation as the logged in user.

My apologies if I sounds like a broken record

Comment: Then you need to fetch the current user, and do a **second** query that uses the information you got from the first.